# WPF DataGrid rows/columns/cells highlighting

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, highlighting

I'm implementing data diff in my project and now i have a need to display my results to user.
(I'm inspecting two arrays of arbitrary data and finding mismatches in them, my results are something like :
"Status : mismatch, Property : ... Index: ..." (some class)). So It's working pretty well by now,first I thought it will be easy to highlight results in DataGrid, but when i started to implement this i realized that I just can't imagine how to get this done...I need to highlight preset cells and rows...Does any common solution exist? P.S DataGrid is binding to some data (using views). I have no much experience in WPF, so don't want to reinvent the wheel, think something should exist (solution, open-source project, code samples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is example of what you need.

1. I assume, that `ChangeItem` is class for storing one line. So in xaml you bind `ChangeItem[]` to `ItemsSource` property of your datagrid.

   ```
   class ChangeItem
   {
       public string Previous { get; set; }
       public string Current  { get; set; }
       public bool HasDiff { return this.Previous != this.Current; } 
   }
   ```
2. In Xaml add special style to your Resources

   ```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasDiff}" Value="true">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
          </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
   ```
3. If you need to support editing and real-time background changes, depending on changes made. Then properly implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in class `ChangeItem`.
4. If you need to have more than 2 states (HasError/NoErrors), then create new enum, representing states. For example:

   ```
   public enum LineState
   {
        Normal,
        SmallError,
        MegaError,
   }
   ```

   And replace `public bool HasDiff { ... }` property with something like `public LineState State { ... }`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this solution, it's not exact what i wanted, i need to highlight cell that was modified, not all the row..How to do this?